# Block for associatedtype in protocol

Tags: swift3, swift-protocols

Here is the example code I learnt here (http://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/06/26/paging/):

```
protocol AsyncGeneratorType {
  associatedtype Element
  associatedtype Fetch
  func next(_ fetchNextBatch: Fetch, _ onFinish: ((Element) -> Void)?)
}

class PagingGenerator<T>: AsyncGeneratorType {

  typealias Element = Array<T>

  typealias Fetch = (_ offset: Int, _ limit: Int, _ completion: (_ result: 
Element) -> Void) -> Void

  var offset:Int
  let limit: Int

  init(startOffset: Int = 0, limit: Int = 25) {
    self.offset = startOffset
    self.limit = limit
  }

  func next(_ fetchNextBatch: Fetch, _ onFinish: ((Element) -> Void)? = nil) {
      fetchNextBatch(offset, limit) { [unowned self] (items) in
        onFinish?(items)
        self.offset += items.count
      }
  }
}
```

The compiler(xcode 8.3.2) gave me error:

> "Type 'PagingGenerator' does not conform to protocol
>   'AsyncGeneratorType'"

The tip from compiler:

> Protocol requires function 'next' with type '((Int, Int, (Array) ->
>   Void) -> Void, ((Array) -> Void)?) -> ()'; do you want to add a
>   stub?
>
> Candidate has non-matching type ' ((Int, Int, (Array) -> Void)
>   -> Void, ((PagingGenerator.Element) -> Void)?) -> ()'

Basically, this is a paginator class. **"Element"** represents content in the page, **"Fetch"** represents block to retrieve elements

I tried without using generics. The error still persist as long as i use "Fetch" as function parameter. 
I would appreciate if someone can give some hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just remove type aliasses and it should compile

```
protocol AsyncGeneratorType {
    associatedtype Element
    associatedtype Fetch
    func next(_ fetchNextBatch: Fetch, _ onFinish: ((Element) -> Void)?)
}

class PagingGenerator<T>: AsyncGeneratorType {
    var offset:Int
    let limit: Int

    init(startOffset: Int = 0, limit: Int = 25) {
        self.offset = startOffset
        self.limit = limit
    }

    func next(_ fetchNextBatch: (_ offset: Int, _ limit: Int, _ completion: (_ result:
        Array<T>) -> Void) -> Void, _ onFinish: ((Array<T>) -> Void)? = nil) {
        fetchNextBatch(offset, limit) { [unowned self] (items) in
            onFinish?(items)
            self.offset += items.count
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try it before and it worked. But i still prefer to use typealias to make that function signature cleaner. I feel like this may be a bug for swift since it works with data types.